# Saving session data for Google Actions with Dialogflow and WebhookClient (v2 API)

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I had been saving my session variables as [contexts](https://dialogflow.com/docs/contexts/contexts-fulfillment), and it had been working fine in previous releases.

This time around, when I checked, this code had stopped working.

My package.json has dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "actions-on-google": "^2.4.0",
    .
    .
    .
    "dialogflow-fulfillment": "^0.6.0"
  }
```

Then, my code goes like

```
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });


    // Handle the Dialogflow intent named 'welcome'.
    function welcome(agent) {
          const sessionVars = {'userLang': 'en',  // possibilites handled - 'en', 'hi'
                          'words': [],
                          'questions': [],
                          'currentIndexPosition': 0,
                          'score': 0,
                        };

          const sessionContext = {'name': KEY_SESSION, 'lifespanCount': 10000, 'parameters': sessionVars};
          agent.setContext(sessionContext);
        .
        .
        .
        //Rest of the code
        }


        // Start a new round of learning by selecting words
        function startLearning(agent) {

        let sessionContext = agent.getContext(KEY_SESSION);
        let sessionParams = sessionContext.parameters;
        let conv = agent.conv();

        conv.ask('Awesome! Let\'s learn a new word. ');
        database_path = DATABASE_PATH_LEARNING_EN;

        return firebaseAdmin.database().ref(database_path)
          .once('value')
          .then( (data) => {

              // --- Code that reads data from database and stores in variable words ---

              // Update session data
              sessionParams.words = utils.getRandomItemList(words, QUESTIONS_PER_PRACTICE);
              let currentIndexPosition = 0;
              sessionParams.currentIndexPosition = currentIndexPosition;

              // --- printing sessionContext value shows correctly updated data here ---    

              // Update session data
              agent.setContext(sessionContext);
            } else {
              conv.close('No words to learn.');
            }
            agent.add(conv);
            return agent;
        });
       }

      // Repeat the word for learning
      function repeatWord(agent) {
        let sessionContext = agent.context.get(KEY_SESSION);
        let sessionParams = sessionContext.parameters;
        agent.add(JSON.stringify(sessionContext));
      }
```

The context is getting set in welcome(). I am able to retrieve it in startLearning(), and printing the sessionContext into the conversation after update also shows me the data was there.
Then, I update the agent context as sessionContext.

In the next intent of the flow - repeatWord (currently, having only code required for debugging), I do not get the updated context value.

I have tried both agent.setContext(sessionContext) and agent.context.set(sessionContext). Both, seem to work the same, and do not work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
conv.data = sessionVars;
```

to set the variables and access them using conv.data in other intents. data will be lost when the conversation ends. use conv.user.storage if you need to persist data across conversations.

Comment: I had read somewhere in the past that conv.data (conversation token) should not be used with API v2. Is my understanding wrong? This worked, but I am not sure if it could lead to any future problems

Comment: I don't think so. check here https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/save-data#nodejs

Answer (score 0):

Although they use the term `lifespanCount` in the documentation, the library just calls this `lifespan` when using `agent.context.set()`

Comment: Sadly doesn't help. I changed the term, but still not getting the values in next intent.